# bcrypt-nodejs compare function always return false

Tags: node.js, bluebird, bcrypt

I'm having problem with bcrypt-nodejs' compare function.
The compare function is returning the false value even the password is the right one.
I've tried everything I could and I don't know the what is wrong with my code.

**My Folder Structure**

```
src
  -config
    -config.js
  -controller
    -AuthenticationController.js
  -models
    -index.js
    -User.js
  -policies
    -AuthenticationControllerPolicy.js
  app.js
  routes.js
 package.json
```

I think the problem is with the **User.js** in models folder.

**User.js**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt-nodejs'))

function hashPassword (user, options) {
  const SALT_FACTOR = 8

  if (!user.changed('password')) {
    return
  }

  return bcrypt
    .genSaltAsync(SALT_FACTOR)
    .then(salt => bcrypt.hashAsync(user.password, salt, null))
    .then(hash => {
      user.setDataValue('password', hash)
    })
}

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: hashPassword,
      beforeUpdate: hashPassword,
      beforeSave: hashPassword
    }
  })

  User.prototype.comparePassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, this.password)
  }

  User.associate = function (models) {
  }

  return User
}
```

**AuthenticationController.js**

```
const {User} = require('../models')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('../config/config')

function jwtSignUser (user) {
  const ONE_WEEK = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  return jwt.sign(user, config.authentication.jwtSecret, {
    expiresIn: ONE_WEEK
  })
}

module.exports = {
  async register (req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body)
      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'This email account is already in use.'
      })
    }
  },
  async login (req, res) {
    try {
      const {email, password} = req.body
      const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      })

      console.log('user BEFORE', user)
      if (!user) {
        console.log('!user')
        return res.status(403).send({
          error: 'The login information was incorrect'
        })
      }

      console.log('user AFTER', user)

      const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(password)
      console.log('isPasswordValid BEFORE : ', isPasswordValid)
      if (!isPasswordValid) {
        console.log('isPasswordValid AFTER : ', isPasswordValid)
        return res.status(403).send({
          error: 'The login information was incorrect'
        })
      }

      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occured trying to log in'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**route.js**

```
const AuthenticationController = require('./controller/AuthenticationController')
const AuthenticationControllerPolicy = require('./policies/AuthenticationControllerPolicy')

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/register',
    AuthenticationControllerPolicy.register,
    AuthenticationController.register)
  app.post('/login',
    AuthenticationController.login)
}
```

You can also check the repo if you want.
[GitHubRepo](https://github.com/WaillLinxenda/tabtracker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `bcrypt-nodejs` appears to be correct. I would verify that both the password coming in and the hash in the database are what you expect them to be (particularly inside the `comparePassword` function) to rule out if it's a data issue or not.

Comment: So may be it was wrong while inserting to the database? I tried to console.log out the both `password` and `this.password` and both are correct. @Ben Hanna

Comment: I found the issue - @Ben Hanna . It was the `hooks`. I removed the `beforeSave` hook and the problem was solved. What happened was the hashing process trigger 2 times `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave` so it was hashing the already hashed password and returning false. Thank you for your help.